# Scilab: gca().grid=[1,1] applies a grid to wrong subplot axes

Tags: grid, subplot, axes, scilab

I'm a bit of a newbie at Scilab / Matlab so I might not know some of the finer details and strategies.

I'm running **`Scilab 6.1.1`** on Windows 10.

I want to plot 2 datasets in the same figure using `subplot` but it seems scilab is doing some weird stuff.

Here's my script:

```py
    Ts = 1/20000; 
    t = 0:Ts:100-Ts; 
    P = mtlb_a(100000+34000*sin(0.2*2*%pi*t),6750*squarewave(0.5*2*%pi*t));
    
    figure(1)
    
    subplot(211)    //top subplot
    gca().filled="off"  //make background transparent
    plot((0:max(size(P))-1) * Ts,P/1000,"-b","LineWidth",2) //plot data
    gca().grid=[1,1]    //gridlines black
    gca().x_label.text="x label for subplot 211"
    
    subplot(212)    //bottom subplot
    gca().filled="off"
    plot((0:max(size(P))-1) * Ts,P/1000,"-b","LineWidth",2)
    gca().data_bounds = [0,65,50,150];  //change axis bounds
    gca().grid=[3,3]    //gridlines green
    gca().x_label.text="x label for subplot 212"
```

This is the result on my machine

[image]

Notice how the gridlines are being applied to the wrong subplots, they are the wrong colors and the wrong spacing. But the other axes properties like the x_label and data_bounds are working fine.

I don't think I'm missing anything, is it a bug? Any ideas how to fix it? or is there a workaround I can do or something? This mostly wouldn't be a problem if the gridline spacings weren't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No problem for me with your code, run as well with 6.1.1 on win10:
[image]

Comment: ok thank you. I also tried on a different Windows machine and it worked fine. I tried reinstalling Scilab on my own machine and still had the same problem. I guess I'll just have to live with it...